# ng-view not updating upon ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-view within my Angular application. within index.html I have a button, When I click on this button I am getting the JSON data, however I cant access my updated scope back into my ng-view template. please examine the code below.
    <

```
div class="row" style="display:none;" id="srhBox" ng-controller="SearchController">
         <button 
            data-channelid="" data-relatedtovideoid="" data-videoduration="" data-videotype="" data-keyword="{{keyword}}"
            ng-click="search($event)" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
</div>
```

Here is controller

```
angular.module('kZoneApp').controller('SearchController', ['$location','$scope', 'dataFactory', '$window', '$routeParams', '$rootScope','$http', function ($location,$scope, dataFactory, $window, $routeParams, $rootScope, $http) {


    $scope.search = function (evt) {


     $location.path("search"); // update ng-view

        var keyword = $(evt.currentTarget).attr("data-keyword");
        var channelid = $(evt.currentTarget).attr("data-channelid");
        var relatedtovideoid = $(evt.currentTarget).attr("data-relatedtovideoid");
        var videoduration =  $(evt.currentTarget).attr("data-videoduration");
        var videotype =  $(evt.currentTarget).attr("data-videotype");

        var url = 'http://xxxx.com/api/Videos/Search?'
        url = url + 'keyword=' + keyword
        url = url + '&channelid=' + channelid
        url = url + '&relatedtovideoid=' + relatedtovideoid
        url = url + '&videoduration=' + videoduration
        url = url + '&videotype=' + videotype

        $http.get(url).
        success(function (data) {

            $scope.searchResults = data;
            console.log(data) // Yes it shows JSON data


           });
    }


}]);
```

and here is code for ng-view template...

```
<div class="col-md-12 " style="padding-top:5px;">
    {{searchResults.nextPageToken}} // This is BLANK
</div>
```

json....

```
{
 "nextPageToken": "CBkQAA",
 "items": [
  {
   "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/B_XTRBSSmBkwVbCPVJmABe4rJpo\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "n8JEY8PKCcI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-06-05T18:51:06.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCY48IObMpigEGsBEtfUUepg",
    "title": "WWE 2K15 The New Day vs Power Rangers Summer Slam wwe 2k15",
    "description": "I created this video with the YouTube Video Editor (http://www.youtube.com/editor)",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/n8JEY8PKCcI/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/n8JEY8PKCcI/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/n8JEY8PKCcI/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Caqueen520",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },..... more items
```

route config.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/search', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/search.html',
        controller: 'SearchController'
    })
```

so  {{searchResults.nextPageToken}} is empty, even though console.log clearly shows it has value. what could be causing this.

**UPDATE**

it seems like the problem is.... I have ng-controller="SearchController" for my button and then i am loading the VIEW (ng-view) using the routes, so angular does not update two controllers with same name on the same page....it updates the first controller & ignores the second one.

Comment: post the value of the json data

Comment: try giving `$scope.searchResults = data.nextPageToken;` and then write `{{searchResults}}` in your output div. check if you get any output then.

Comment: Can you show your route config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though $http takes care of running digest cycle which takes care of two way biding, try adding a timeout using $timeout because it also runs the digest cycle.

```
       $http.get(url)
       .success(function (data) {
        $timeout(function () {
          $scope.searchResults = data;
          console.log(data) // Yes it shows JSON data
        }, 100);
       });
```

As per your route config, `/search` view uses the same controller `SearchController`. So when you load the `/search` view using `$location.path('/search')` the controller is reinitialized so `$scope.searchResults` will be undefined. You will have to have to search login inside a different controller and use that controller in the route config.

OR you can have a hidden partial view and show it only when you have the searchResults using `ng-if` directive.

So in the main view have this html

```
<div ng-if="searchResults" class="col-md-12 " style="padding-top:5px;">
    {{searchResults.nextPageToken}} // This is BLANK
</div>
```

And remove the `$location.path('/search')` from `$scope.search` method in the SearchController.

Comment: no effect with above suggestion, I added the routeConfig code to the question. Funny think is...if I setup an another tag/button on the same page "search.html", then it works...it only does not work while i am landing on the new route using location.path().

Comment: you think it would make more sense to create a global function "$rootScope.search", within the root of application, and just call it from any view? I am using ng-view and I think i will run into problems if I put my Search button in its own controller controller. say i am on search.html and press search button again, angular will expect a "search" function within searchController as well.